# Issue converting js to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want this snake app, as a react component and I have been working all day with no solution. I recently deleted what I had and accidentally closed the file, so I'm starting from scratch. The reason I want it in the component, is because I want to access the state and props for other uses.

```js
/**
 * Namespace
 */
var Game = Game || {};
var Keyboard = Keyboard || {};
var Component = Component || {};

/**
 * Keyboard Map
 */
Keyboard.Keymap = {
  37: 'left',
  38: 'up',
  39: 'right',
  40: 'down'
};

/**
 * Keyboard Events
 */
Keyboard.ControllerEvents = function() {

  // Setts
  var self = this;
  this.pressKey = null;
  this.keymap = Keyboard.Keymap;

  // Keydown Event
  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    self.pressKey = event.which;
  };

  // Get Key
  this.getKey = function() {
    return this.keymap[this.pressKey];
  };
};

/**
 * Game Component Stage
 */
Component.Stage = function(canvas, conf) {

  // Sets
  this.keyEvent = new Keyboard.ControllerEvents();
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.length = [];
  this.food = {};
  this.score = 0;
  this.direction = 'right';
  this.conf = {
    cw: 10,
    size: 5,
    fps: 1000
  };

  // Merge Conf
  if (typeof conf == 'object') {
    for (var key in conf) {
      if (conf.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.conf[key] = conf[key];
      }
    }
  }

};

/**
 * Game Component Snake
 */
Component.Snake = function(canvas, conf) {

  // Game Stage
  this.stage = new Component.Stage(canvas, conf);

  // Init Snake
  this.initSnake = function() {

    // Itaration in Snake Conf Size
    for (var i = 0; i < this.stage.conf.size; i++) {

      // Add Snake Cells
      this.stage.length.push({
        x: i,
        y: 0
      });
    }
  };

  // Call init Snake
  this.initSnake();

  // Init Food  
  this.initFood = function() {

    // Add food on stage
    this.stage.food = {
      x: Math.round(Math.random() * (this.stage.width - this.stage.conf.cw) / this.stage.conf.cw),
      y: Math.round(Math.random() * (this.stage.height - this.stage.conf.cw) / this.stage.conf.cw),
    };
  };

  // Init Food
  this.initFood();

  // Restart Stage
  this.restart = function() {
    this.stage.length = [];
    this.stage.food = {};
    this.stage.score = 0;
    this.stage.direction = 'right';
    this.stage.keyEvent.pressKey = null;
    this.initSnake();
    this.initFood();
  };
};

/**
 * Game Draw
 */
Game.Draw = function(context, snake) {

  // Draw Stage
  this.drawStage = function() {

    // Check Keypress And Set Stage direction
    var keyPress = snake.stage.keyEvent.getKey();
    if (typeof(keyPress) != 'undefined') {
      snake.stage.direction = keyPress;
    }

    // Draw White Stage
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, snake.stage.width, snake.stage.height);

    // Snake Position
    var nx = snake.stage.length[0].x;
    var ny = snake.stage.length[0].y;

    // Add position by stage direction
    switch (snake.stage.direction) {
      case 'right':
        nx++;
        break;
      case 'left':
        nx--;
        break;
      case 'up':
        ny--;
        break;
      case 'down':
        ny++;
        break;
    }

    // Check Collision
    if (this.collision(nx, ny) == true) {
      snake.restart();
      return;
    }

    // Logic of Snake food
    if (nx == snake.stage.food.x && ny == snake.stage.food.y) {
      var tail = {
        x: nx,
        y: ny
      };
      snake.stage.score++;
      snake.initFood();
    } else {
      var tail = snake.stage.length.pop();
      tail.x = nx;
      tail.y = ny;
    }
    snake.stage.length.unshift(tail);

    // Draw Snake
    for (var i = 0; i < snake.stage.length.length; i++) {
      var cell = snake.stage.length[i];
      this.drawCell(cell.x, cell.y);
    }

    // Draw Food
    this.drawCell(snake.stage.food.x, snake.stage.food.y);

    // Draw Score
    context.fillText('Score: ' + snake.stage.score, 5, (snake.stage.height - 5));
  };

  // Draw Cell
  this.drawCell = function(x, y) {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(170, 170, 170)';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc((x * snake.stage.conf.cw + 6), (y * snake.stage.conf.cw + 6), 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fill();
  };

  // Check Collision with walls
  this.collision = function(nx, ny) {
    if (nx == -1 || nx == (snake.stage.width / snake.stage.conf.cw) || ny == -1 || ny == (snake.stage.height / snake.stage.conf.cw)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};


/**
 * Game Snake
 */
Game.Snake = function(elementId, conf) {

  // Sets
  var canvas = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var snake = new Component.Snake(canvas, conf);
  var gameDraw = new Game.Draw(context, snake);

  // Game Interval
  setInterval(function() {
    gameDraw.drawStage();
  }, snake.stage.conf.fps);
};


/**
 * Window Load
 */
window.onload = function() {
  var snake = new Game.Snake('stage', {
    fps: 100,
    size: 4
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

canvas {
  border: 2px solid rgb(151, 149, 149);
}
```

```html
<h3>Simple Snake Game</h3>
<canvas id="stage" height="400" width="520"></canvas>
```

I've made all the custom mods that I want, however, because the JavaScript is out side of the component, I can't access the "auth" state and dispatch an action. any help would be awesome!

EDIT:

I want to access props to call this function when a user collides.

```
// Check Collision
    if (this.collision(nx, ny) == true) {
      this.props.actions.myCustomAction(this.props.auth, snake.stage.score
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the JS in a React component or an imported library, but remove the window onload code:

```
/**
 * Window Load
 */
window.onload = function() {
  var snake = new Game.Snake('stage', {fps: 100, size: 4});
};
```

And add this to your React Component:

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.snake = null;
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.snake = new Game.Snake('stage', {fps: 100, size: 4});
}
```

Then you can access this.snake for state, etc.

Comment: So thats what I have so far, however, I want to make a call/check on the // Check Collision function... If they collide, I want to access this.props.auth and dispatch an action. See edit above